# Matlabs xcorr function in c

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I am using the function

```
in = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
lag = 8;
out = xcorr(in, lag)
```

it produces the output:

```
out = [175,000000000000, 238,000000000000, 308, 384, 465, 550, 638, 728, 819, 728, 638, 550, 465, 384, 308, 238, 175,000000000000];
```

I do not understand from Matlabs documentation how to get those values. Is there any kind of formula that I can use for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general matlab documentation put the formulas in a chapter named **More about**, look at this chapter to understand which formula matlab implements. 
This is the link to the **More about** chapter of the *xcorr* function.
https://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html#bubr0h6

For greater clarity look at this code:

```
in = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
lag = 8;
N = length(in);
correlation = zeros(2*lag,1);
for m = -8:8
    correlation(m+8+1) = sum(in.*[zeros(1,abs(m)) in(1:N-abs(m))]);
end
```

where `sum(in.*[zeros(1,abs(m)) in(1:N-abs(m))]);` computes the sum of the product beetween `in` and its shifted version. To compute the shifted version of  *in* simply padding the first m elements with zero and the N-m element are in(1:N-m). I've used the abs because the lag *m* is either negative or positive. 
Try the code and also print `[zeros(1,abs(m)) in(1:N-abs(m))]` for various value of *m* to understand better how look the shifted version of the vector.

For homework: why we use `[zeros(1,abs(m)) in(1:N-abs(m))]` and not `[zeros(1,abs(m)) in(1:N)]`?
P.s in this case you are calculating the autocorrelation, so the *y* vector is *x*.
For more details about the theory check the **Reference** chapter to see which books matlab refers.

Comment: Yes, I of course saw that already. However I do not really understand the formulas, especially I do not really see how the lag parameter is treated here. Is there any better explanation for that?

Comment: to compute the cross correlation simply you take the vector y and shift it from -inf to +inf, so the cross correlation is function of the shift of y. However the vectors have limitated range, so there is no necessity to compute from - inf to inf. In general the width of the cross correlation is two times the width of the maximum vector. For example if you have a vector X of dim 30 and a vector Y of dim 50 the cross correlation between X and Y has a width of 100. Now according to matlab doc of xcorr you can specifies the maximum lag to constraint the xcorr to -lag to lag